# Pre-filled input fields in price filter

Tags: usability, gui-design, e-commerce, best-practice

We are designing e-commerce site for one of our clients. We have decided to have input fields for filtering according to price. The client asked if min price and max price should be pre-filled by default with the value of the cheapest and the most expensive product.

Does it make sense to have any default value in those fields?

Comment: Makes sense why allow values to be selected that would return no products in a search?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, It is good to have the minimum and maximum value of the products displayed in the search filter but it should be presented in a way that user should understand the purpose of having it.

Prefilling the input fields might not be the best solution as the user will not have any idea why it starts from some value and ends at one. Providing a message in the filter below the input fields will be the best solution or asking the user to provide the minimum value and maximum value by using the placeholder with the products available price will also be the best solution.

Adding sliders instead of text fields also gives a rich user's experience.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have price sliders attached to the inputs, min and max can be a useful information that provides a comparison method (even more if you choose a fixed width for the slider).

In this case, using a slider, the inputs are filled after the user choose a value on the slider and the min and max can be displayed also as labels. I found some example [here](http://baymard.com/blog/slider-interfaces).

If you have just the inputs, min and max are not relevant for the filtering because the results will be the same and it is better to avoid a validation or having a value inserted that is not in the interval. In this case, i find better to don't display the min and max.